# Is there a way to calculate the size of a query generated from sqlAppendTable()?

Tags: r, postgresql, r-dbi

I am currently running into an issue where the postgres query I am attempting to execute is exceeding the maximum size of a postgres query in bytes - 16777216bytes (16MB).

I am using the `sqlAppendTable(con, data, values)` function which I believe generates an SQL query from a dataframe object which appends my data to the specified table.

Seeing as I know the contents of the dataframe being passed into the sqlAppendTable function. I am wondering if there is a way to calculate what the resulting query size will be so that I can split the dataframe into chunks that will fit within the limit?

Thanks.